# Flask SQLAlchemy table is not created

Tags: flask, sqlalchemy

I'm trying to create an table in my flask application using flask_sqlalchemy

application.py

```
app = Flask(__name__)
app.config['SQLALCHEMY_DATABASE_URI'] = "postgres+psycopg2://postgres:2503@localhost:5432/data"
app.config['SQLALCHEMY_TRACK_MODIFICATIONS'] = False
connection = SQLAlchemy(app)

app.config["SESSION_PERMANENT"] = False
app.config["SESSION_TYPE"] = "filesystem"
session = Session(app)

# Set up database
engine = create_engine(os.getenv("DATABASE_CONNECT"))
db = scoped_session(sessionmaker(bind=engine))

if __name__ == "__main__":
    with app.app_context():
        connection.create_all()
        connection.session.commit()
```

models.py

```
from flask_sqlalchemy import SQLAlchemy

db = SQLAlchemy()

class Person(db.Model):
    __tablename__ = "persons"
    id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True)
    name = db.Column(db.String, nullable=False)
    password = db.Column(db.String, nullable=False)
```

If I run:
`python application.py`
It returned without any error but the tabel is not created in the database.
Anybody help me to resolve this problem..!!

Answer (score 0):

The tables would normally be created when you call `connection.create_all()`. However, you have to add your tables (i.e. models) to that `connection` object. In your case you are created a new `SQLAlchemy` object called `db` and added your models to that. Thus you would need to do a `db.create_all()` to create those tables instead of `connection.create_all()`.

I don't know why you need two `SQLAchemy` objects from what you've posted, so unless you have a compelling reason, get rid of one of them so there isn't any confusion.

The [docs](https://flask-sqlalchemy.palletsprojects.com/en/2.x/quickstart/) have a good minimal example to help you.